# Random Read/Writes in HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, filesystems, hdfs

I read that random read and writes are not present in `Hadoop HDFS`. But, arguments for write in `DFSOutputStream` is

```
void write(byte buf[], int off, int len)
void write(int b)
```

Similarly, arguments for read in `DFSInputStream` is

```
int read(byte buf[], int off, int len)

int read()
```

OffSet parameter can be seen in both read/write calls to `HDFS`. Why is it needed, if `MapReduce` framework only used to add data at last position? How is "offset" parameter used in `HDFS` ? Does HDFS writes always append only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter **int off** doesn't represent a random point inside the input file. It is actually the **offset within the byte[ ]** from where data will be written inside the byte[ ] till the **len** number of bytes. **For example**, suppose you have written

```
byte buf[15];
read(buf, 5, 10);
```

This will read data from the **start of the input file** and **not from he 5th byte** of the file. But the array **buf[ ]** will be filled from **5th byte till the last byte(5+10)**.

To cross check you can use some different value for the **parameter off**. Whatever value you give for **off**, data will always be read from the **start of the file(if you have not used seek explicitly)**.

One point to note here is that the size of the array **must not be less that off+len**.

Run this example for a clear understanding :

```
public class ReadHdfsFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.addResource(new Path("/Users/miqbal1/hadoop-eco/hadoop-1.1.2/conf/core-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path("/Users/miqbal1/hadoop-eco/hadoop-1.1.2/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        FSDataInputStream in = fs.open(new Path("/demo.txt"));

        //Filling the array b1 from the 5th byte
        int charPos = 0;
        byte[] b1 = new byte[10];
        int bytesRead = in.read(b1, 5, 5);
        System.out.println("Bytes Read : " + bytesRead);
        String s = new String(b1, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("Printing char by char(you'll see first 5 bytes as blank)...");
        for(char c : s.toCharArray()){
            System.out.println("Character " + ++charPos + " : " + c);

        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Changing offset value....");

        //Filling the array b2 from the 10th byte
        in.seek(0);
        charPos = 0;
        byte[] b2 = new byte[15];
        bytesRead = in.read(b2, 10, 5);
        System.out.println("Bytes Read : " + bytesRead);
        s = new String(b2, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("Printing char by char(you'll see first 10 bytes as blank)...");
        for(char c : s.toCharArray()){
            System.out.println("Character " + ++charPos + " : " + c);
        }

        System.out.println("DONE!!!");
        in.close();
        fs.close();
    }
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks Tariq. I have a question. you have told that "This will read data from the start of the input file and not from he 5th byte of the file." Isn't the data to be read from last read position , rather than the start of the file? . Also, Is the same case with write too?

Comment: You are correct. I have used **seek** that's why pointer will go back to the start of the file. If you don't use seek file will be read from the point you had left earlier.

Comment: It was just to explain the concept.

Comment: is the same case with the writes?

Comment: @GoT There are two kinds of writes, truncate then append and append from the end of file.  I also want to put it clear that by using seek then read, hdfs actually supports random read.

Answer (score 0):

"bytesRead = in.read(b2, 10, 5);" is just one interface from FSDataInputStream. another interface in.read(postion, buffer, offset, len) support random read. you could also refer the TestDFSIO random read case.

HDFS doesn't support random write in deed.